# Generic[type[Enum], Protocol[DataFrame]] Dataset with mapped to enum types

Tags: python, pandas, generics, protocols

Below is my solution for managing multiple DataFrames, in an abstract enough way that it may apply to objects outside of a `pandas.DataFrame` hence the `Protocol` `SupportsGetAndSetItemSequence`.

This solution supports a `MultiIndex` index and assumes columns will be a single `Index`

Typically I would stuff all of the data into a single DataFrame but working with geospatial timeseries data often leads to a misaligned indices.

Note: I am using `pyright` for static type analysis and python 3.10

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import enum
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Any, overload, Sequence, TypeGuard, Protocol

from typing_extensions import Self
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.indexes.category import CategoricalIndex


Key_T_co = TypeVar("Key_T_co", contravariant=True)


class SupportsGetAndSetItemSequence(Protocol[Key_T_co]):
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, __key: list[Key_T_co]) -> Self:
        ...

    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, __key: Key_T_co) -> Self:
        ...

    def __setitem__(self, __key: list[Key_T_co] | Key_T_co, __value: Any) -> None:
        ...


class Coordinate(enum.Enum):
    @classmethod
    def to_index(cls) -> CategoricalIndex:
        return CategoricalIndex(cls.to_list(), name=cls, dtype="category")

    @classmethod
    def to_list(cls) -> list[Self]:
        return list(cls)


Coord_T = TypeVar("Coord_T", bound=Coordinate)
Value_T = TypeVar("Value_T", bound=SupportsGetAndSetItemSequence)



def is_coordinate_subclass(cls: type[Coord_T] | Any) -> TypeGuard[type[Coord_T]]:
    if cls is Coordinate:
        raise TypeError("Coordinate is not a valid Coordinate subclass")
    return isinstance(cls, type) and issubclass(cls, Coordinate)


NodeStore = dict[type[Coord_T], Value_T]


class Dataset(Generic[Coord_T, Value_T]):
    __slots__ = ("_nodes",)

    def __init__(self, nodes: NodeStore[Coord_T, Value_T] | None = None) -> None:
        self._nodes = nodes or {}

    @property
    def nodes(self) -> NodeStore[Coord_T, Value_T]:
        return self._nodes

    @staticmethod
    def _get_coordinate(coord: Any) -> type[Coord_T]:
        if is_coordinate_subclass(coord):
            return coord
        elif isinstance(coord, Sequence):
            return type(coord[0])
        else:
            return type(coord)

    def __getitem__(self, key: type[Coord_T] | Sequence[Coord_T] | Coord_T) -> Value_T:
        coord = self._get_coordinate(key)
        return self._nodes[coord] if coord == key else self._nodes[coord][key]

    def __setitem__(self, key: type[Coord_T] | Sequence[Coord_T] | Coord_T, value: Any) -> None:
        coord = self._get_coordinate(key)
        if coord == key or coord not in self.nodes.keys():
            self.nodes[coord] = value
        else:
            self.nodes[coord][key] = value

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return "\n".join(f"{self.__class__.__name__}[{k.__name__}]\n{v}" for k, v in self.nodes.items())
```

#### Usage

```
class ExampleA(Coordinate):
    one = "cat"
    two = "dog"
    three = "bird"


class ExampleB(Coordinate):
    one = "dog"


class ExampleC(Coordinate):
    one = "bird"


def main():
    ds = Dataset[ExampleA | ExampleB, pd.DataFrame](
        {
            ExampleA: pd.DataFrame(
                {ExampleA.one: [1]},
                index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1, 2)], names=["x", "y"]),
            )
        }
    )

    ds[ExampleA].columns.rename(ExampleA, inplace=True)  # Ok
    ds[ExampleA.two] = [5]  # Ok
    ds[ExampleA.two] += ds[ExampleA.two]  # Ok
    ds[ExampleA.three] = ds[[ExampleA.one, ExampleA.two]].sum(axis=1)  # Ok
    
    ds[ExampleB.one] = pd.DataFrame({ExampleB.one: [2]}, columns=ExampleB.to_index())  # Ok
    
    df1 = ds[ExampleA]  # Ok
    df2 = ds[ExampleB]  # Ok
    print(ds)
    # Dataset[ExampleA]
    # <enum 'ExampleA'>  ExampleA.one  ExampleA.two  ExampleA.three
    # x y                                                          
    # 1 2                           1            10              11
    # Dataset[ExampleB]
    # <enum 'ExampleB'>  ExampleB.one
    # 0                             2
    ds[ExampleC] = pd.DataFrame({ExampleC.one: [3]})  # Argument of Type "ExampleC" cannot be assigned ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```